# using base pointer to use derived objects functions

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

How can i get my Base pointer to instantiate a derived object and use its functions? Is there a way to type cast this like java?
Consider this sample code:

```
int main(){
    cBase *pBase = 0;
    if (1 < 2)
    {
        pBase = new cDerived;
    }
}

class cBase
 {public:
     virtual void printMe()
          {
             std::cout << "printed cBase" << endl;
           }
};

class cDerived: public cBase
{public:
    virtual void printMe()
         {
            std:: cout << "printed cDerived" << endl;
          }
};
```

However when i do this; it gives me an error "Expression must have class type".

```
cBase *pBase = 0;
    if (1 < 2)
    {
        pBase = new cDerived;
        pBase.printMe();
    }
```

Comment: Where is your definition of cBase?

Comment: does it need one? i just made this example up

Comment: `pBase.printMe();` ===> `pBase->printMe();`, and `printMe()` had better be a member (virtual or otherwise) of `cBase`.

Comment: It needs it to be working code. Do you have a definition of `cBase` with a virtual function `printMe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix it like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class cBase
 {
    public:
        virtual ~cBase() {};
        virtual void printMe()
        {
         std::cout << "printed cBase" << endl;
        }
};

class cDerived: public cBase
{public:
    virtual void printMe()
         {
            std:: cout << "printed cDerived" << endl;
          }
};

int main(){
    cBase *pBase = 0;
    if (1 < 2)
    {
        pBase = new cDerived;
        pBase->printMe();
        delete pBase;
    }
}
```

Steps to fix.

1. Move `main` function after declaration of `cBase` and `cDerived` classes or forward declare those classes before `main`.
2. Change `pBase.printMe()` to `pBase->printMe()`. Since `pBase` is a pointer you must dereference it before accessing its members. `pBase->printMe()` is like shorthand for `(*pBase).printMe()`

Plus a few other bits of housekeeping. Delete the `pBase` object and since you are deleting a derived class (`cDerived`) using a pointer to a base class (`cBase`) you must declare the base classes destructor virtual, or the `cBase` destructor will be called when `pBase` is deleted when you really wanted the `cDerived` destructor to be called here.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, in order to get to the method/field of a pointer to a class/structure, you have to use the -> operator.